# changing data types of multiple columns at once in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 30 columns. when I load the data with `pd.read_csv()` method, all the columns' data types by default is set to `object`.

I want to change `col-1` & `col-5` to `int` & rest of the columns to `category`.

my question is, how can I set the remaining columns to `category` at once,

I know I can do something cumbersome like below

```
    +------------------------------------------------+
    | df['col-1'] = df['col-1'].astype('int)         |
    +------------------------------------------------+
    | df['col-2'] = df['col-2'].astype('category')   |
    | ...                                            |
    | df['col-5'] = df['col-5'].astype('int')        |
    +------------------------------------------------+
    | ...                                            |
    | df['col-29'] = df['col-29'].astype('category') |
    +------------------------------------------------+
    | df['col-30'] = df['col-30'].astype('category') |
    +------------------------------------------------+
```

is there any way I could do something like below while reading the csv

`pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', dtype={('col-1','col-5') : int, 'rest' : category})`?

is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use `astype` in a for loop.

```
cat_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['col1', 'col5']]

for col in cat_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

Answer (score 5):

Initialise a dictionary mapping column names to the required types, then pass the dictionary to [**`DataFrame.astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
dtypes = {c: 'category' for c in df}
dtypes.update({c: 'int' for c in ('col1', 'col5')}

out = df.astype(dtypes)
```

Note that you'll still need to explicitly enumerate every column — there currently isn't any scope for specifying contiguous slices to `astype`.

---

Alternatively, you'd do

```
int64_cols = ['col1', 'col5'] 
df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(int64_cols)] = (
      df[df.columns.difference(int64_cols)].astype('category'))

df.loc[int64_cols] = df.loc[int64_cols].astype(int)
```

Which is two calls to `astype` instead of one.

Comment: Thank you very much & really appreciate your time. since, I'm a beginner in python/pandas , It was easy for me to understand @Erfan answer & was able to tweak it to other situations. hence, I accepted his answer. no doubt your answer looks more pro. I hope I can dissect  your answer to get some advance tips.

Comment: @Tommy I undetstand. What you could do instead is upvote both of our answers, even if you can only accept one.

Comment: Done. I am able to now. just a while ago I couldn't. coz' I had less than 15 reputations..